# Is there a way to keep all windows in focus within a Windows Forms application?

Tags: c#, winforms, focus, autofocus

I have an application that some times requires the user to have two forms open at a time. I have the main 'home' form window, but also a calculator form window. It isn't a normal calculator so I would like the calculator to stay within the one application.

When filling out the main form, the calculator is needed to work out some data to input. Only problem is, when `calculator.ShowDialog()` is used, the main form loses focus. The calculator is opened to the right of the main window. So ideally, I would have which ever window is clicked, gain focus.

Comment: The whole point of focusing on a window is to, well... focus on it. If you want to focus on two, that will defeat the purpose.

Comment: If you want to simply switch between the two, you should use `Form.Show()` where you won't need to exit one to use the other. Another solution would be to have the calculator be part of the main app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `form.Show()` instead of `ShowDialog`

Comment: I will be honest, I was unaware that Show() didn't cause loss of focus.

Comment: It does cause loss of focus, but unlike `ShowDialog()` you can switch between the two.

Answer (score 0):

Me thinks that you can add Code line `calculator.Activate();`